# Correct workflow for modal forms in django (example from 'effective django')

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-class-based-views

The example setup from the 'effective django' tutorial works in the following manner:

- On the contacts_list page, the user clicks 'delete'.
- The DeleteView re-directs to the confirm delete page.
- The user clicks the confirm (or cancel) button and is redirected back to contacts_list page.

What I would like to do instead is:

- click 'delete' and pop up a bootstrap modal
- confirm delete (or cancel) in the modal
- then return to the contacts_list page.
- Additionally I would like to do the same for edit and create. Delete just seemed like the simplest case.

Looking up similar topics, it appears modals don't really call a link(/view)  and jquery/ajax should be able to solve the issue. I am still a little unclear on the concepts and best practices. Any insights appreciated.

url.py

```
url(r'^$', contacts.views.ContactListView.as_view(), name='contacts-list',), 
url(r'^new$', cts.views.CreateContactView.as_view(), name='contacts-new',),
url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)$', contacts.views.UpdateContactView.as_view(), name='contacts-edit',), 
url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)$', contacts.views.DeleteContactView.as_view(), name='contacts-delete',), 
url(r'^detail/(?P<pk>\d+)$', contacts.views.ContactDetailView.as_view(), name='contacts-view',),
```

views.py

```
class ContactListView(ListView):
    model = Contact
    template_name = 'contact_list.html'

class DeleteContactView(DeleteView):
    model = Contact
    template_name = 'delete_contact.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('contacts-list')
```

contact_list.html

```
{% for contact in object_list %}
    <li><h3>{{ contact.first_name }} </h3>
        <a href="{% url "contacts-edit" pk=contact.id %}">edit</a>
        <a href="{% url "contacts-delete" pk=contact.id %}">delete</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to omit the validation step provided by django's DeleteView.
Do not bother sending ajax calls.

First, figure out how to display the modal form.

Then you just have to declare the form method as POST (GET would give you the confirmation template) and leave the action as it is.